# script for windows to read variables from a properties file and replace in xml file. Can be perl script, python, powershell or any windows scripting

Tags: windows

I have a properties file which contains some variable values and some xml files in which those variable values need to replaced. I want a script that would read those variable values and put the values of those variables in the xml files.

var.properties file looks like below:

```
@VAR_A@=Value_A
@VAR_B@=Value_B
@VAR_C@=Value_C
```

var.xml file looks like below:

```
<property>
    <name>instanceId</name>
    <value>@VAR_C@</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>rootPath</name>
    <value>/services/@VAR_A@</value>
</property>
```

The requirement is of windows script that would read the variable values from var.properties file and replace the variable values in var.xml file and give the output in var.xml file as below:

```
<property>
        <name>instanceId</name>
        <value>Value_C</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>rootPath</name>
        <value>/services/Value_A</value>
    </property>
```

The requirement is for windows and I'm very much new in windows. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's a standard command on Linux, and you can imagine it being useful on Windows, somebody has probably already ported it. https://github.com/a8m/envsubst/issues/17

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any [mre]? ([ask])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please investigate one of many possible solutions represented by following code

- read whole file *var.property* and fill `%vars` hash with split on `[=\s]+`
- read whole file *var.xml* into variable `$data`
- utilize power of regex to make substitution of `@VAR_[A,B,C]` in `$data` variable with real values

NOTE: this solution assumes that both files are small enough and do not utilize XML modules for simplicity, result is printed in terminal window

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $vars = 'var.property';
my $xml  = 'var.xml';
my(%vars, $data, $fh);

open $fh, '<', $vars
        or die "Couldn't open $vars";
%vars = do { local $/; split(/[=\s]+/, <$fh>) };
close $fh;

open $fh, '<', $xml
        or die "Couldn't open $xml";
$data = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;

$data =~ s/(\@VAR_[A,B,C]\@)/$vars{$1}/ge;

say $data;
```

Output

```
<property>
    <name>instanceId</name>
    <value>Value_C</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>rootPath</name>
    <value>/services/Value_A</value>
</property>
```

To save result into `var.xml` substitute `say $data` with following code

```
open $fh, '>', $xml
    or die "Couldn't open $xml for write";
say $fh $data;
close $fh;
```

Reference: [$/](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#Variables-related-to-filehandles), [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open), [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split), [regex](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre), [hash basics](https://www.perl.com/article/27/2013/6/16/Perl-hash-basics-create-update-loop-delete-and-sort/)

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer @Polar Bear. Actually the var.properties file doesn't only include the variables that I mentioned. It includes many others too like -"@DEV_VAR_2_Value@=NeW_dev_2-val" and many more like this. Can you please help me with the regex for it? The required regex should contain any variable that starts with "@" , ends with "@" and any characters in between. Thanks in advance.